# Pod with 2 containers and Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

If I have a pod with 2 containers, how can i exec into a specific container from Dashbaord.

[image: Details of question]

Answer (score 1):

You can click on container name and switch to different container.

[image]

Comment: awesome answer. didnt see that option before. thank you